# HTML autofocus does not work, and scripts haven't solved it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My password input field uses the "autofocus" attribute but it doesn't autofocus.  I suspected that some javascript or jquery would solve the problem, so I have tried many permutations of scripts I found in articles on the web to get around this problem, but still not solved.

Below is a minimal version of the html code.  The email input field has the "autofocus" attribute, and there are four other scripts on the page, but none of them causes autofocus.  Browser is Firefox, recent version, so browser support is not the issue.

The html code:

```
<form name="thisform" id="thisform">

<div class="EMail_Pwd">
    <input type="text" class="signup_join" autofocus placeholder="Your email address" id="email_field" name="email_field" style="width:55%; margin-left: 0%" required>
<script>
    if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
      document.getElementById("email_field").focus();
    }
  </script>
</div>

<script>
$('input[name="email_field"]').focus();
</script>

        <div class="EMail_Pwd">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Your password 8 characters minimum" class="signup_join" minlength="8" name="passwd" style="width:55%; margin-left: 0%" required></div><br><br>

</form>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("email_field").autofocus; 
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#email_field").focus();
});
</script>
```

The relevant css:

```
.EMail_Pwd{
    font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13pt;
    input size: 200px;
}

.signup_join{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: CamphorW01-Thin, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-family: camphorW01-Thin,calibri,arial;
    font-size: 12pt;
    autofocus: true;
}

.signup_join{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: camphorW01-Thin,calibri,arial;
    font-size: 18pt;
}
```

Nothing shows up in the dev console regarding the scripts.  I don't understand why the "autofocus" attribute is not enough, but in this case it's not.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

EDIT:  I found applying the following script that the email field DOES have focus, but my only problem now is that the cursor is not positioned in the field, so the end-user doesn't know it's focused.

Now I'm trying to position the cursor.

This script sets the focus:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#email_field").focus();
```

});

This script checks to see if the field has focus (it does).

```
<script>{
var hasFocus = $('#email_field').is(':focus');
var output = "Focus = " + hasFocus;
console.log(output);
}
</script>
```

Comment: You have the autofocus set on the first text input with the id of 'email_field'. Is this intended?

Comment: On page load, I want the cursor autofocused in the email_field; the cursor should show there, and there is a green border around the field when it's focused.  I hope that answers your question, if not, please ask.  Thanks.

Comment: When I tested your code, the HTML alone focused the text input. If the email text box is being auto focused then you can't also auto focus the password text box.

Comment: I'm not trying to autofocus the password box, just the email box.  But you said the email text box is being focused, because that's not what I see.  I'm on Firefox.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe this is a bug with Firefox and that it isn't current possible. Perhaps you could try using an earlier version of Firefox?

Comment: I don't think this is a bug in Firefox -- at least I haven't seen any other mention of it being a bug in the most recent versions (since 52).

Comment: If you can't .focus() can you .click()?

Comment: Please see the edit I posted above.  Now I just need to get the cursor to blink in that field, and its green border should show up (so the user knows it's focused).

Comment: As far as i see, there is nothing wrong with the code. It is blinking as expected and the outline shows up.

Comment: Rüzgar, what version of Firefox are you using?  I don't see what you see.  Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the `camphorW01-Thin` font family has problems. I don't see any font import, and for sure this is not an standard one.

Comment: I changed it to Arial, but no difference.  There is a font import elsewhere in the code.